# How to add MediaWiki on Bitnami Joomla Instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-launcher

My Joomla instance on Google Cloud Platform is running.

Now I want to make a wiki using MediaWiki on the same instance. I know I can install it manually but I can easyly create a new instance with Cloud Launcher, I can select MediaWiki and I will have a new instance running with my wiki.

So, is there any way to easyly install MediaWiki on the Joomla instance? Maybe adding some packages... or anything? Without creating new instance.

Thanks!

Israel.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami has a MediaWiki application module you can install in the top of your Joomla instance. You can find it on the following link: https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp/modules. Once you are there, you just only need to look up for MediaWiki.

Once you get the download link of the installer you could follow the next steps to install the MediaWiki module:

- Connect to your instance through SSH.
- Use wget to download the installer to your instance:

`wget https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacks/mediawiki/1.27.1-0/bitnami-mediawiki-1.27.1-0-module-linux-x64-installer.run`

- Give execution permissions to the installer:

`chmod +x bitnami-mediawiki-1.27.1-0-module-linux-x64-installer.run`

- Execute it with `sudo`:

`sudo ./bitnami-mediawiki-1.27.1-0-module-linux-x64-installer.run`

- Complete the wizard.

  - When the installer asks you to `select a folder []`, you have to introduce `/opt/bitnami/`
  - When the installer asks you to `Enter the existing MySQL password for Bitnami`, you have to introduce the Admin password you got when you launched the instance for the first time.

Once the installer finishes, you can access MediaWiki in the `http://YOURDOMAIN/mediawiki` URL.

Hope it helps.